# Laravel modal datatables update

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable, modal-dialog, yajra-datatable

In view there is a button called **'Add/Edit product'**,when I click it and input some values in qty fields then below 'Add/Edit product' button a table will be created.

My view:

[image]
[image]

I want to change/update data in modal qty value when I change it in another table.
I did it little bit but it change only one page in modal:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I used yajra data-table in the modal.
My modal view:

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="productmodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog prod_dia">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add /Edit Product</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <section class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <b>Add /Edit Product</b>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body product_body">


        <div class="table-responsive maindiv"> 
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered prdb" id="productid">
          <form name="proform">
            <thead>
              <th>Product</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Qty</th>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

             @foreach($datapr as $k)
              <tr>
                <td>{{$k->brand}}-{{$k->pcode}}-{{$k->pgroup}}<input type="hidden" data-pcode='{{$k->pcode}}'  class="qtyforpcode"></td>
                <td>{{$k->price}}</td>
                <td>

                      <input type="text" data-prid='{{$k->prid}}' data-brand='{{$k->brand}}' data-price='{{$k->price}}' data-pgroup='{{$k->pgroup}}' data-sprice='{{$k->sprice}}' data-pcode='{{$k->pcode}}' name="pr_qty" id="qty" class="form-control qty">

                </td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>

          </table>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="submit" value="Done" id="doneproduct" class="btn btn-primary customclose">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </form>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

In my jQuery where I try to update modal(but it only changes one page in modal)

```
$('.qtypr').on('change',function(){
var ttr=$(this).parent().parent();
var qty=ttr.find('.qtypr').val();//new value 
var pcode=ttr.find('.qtypr').data('pcode');
console.log(qty);
console.log(pcode);


$('#productmodal .prod_dia .product_body .maindiv .prdb tr').each(function(){

var pcodetable=$(this).find('.qtyforpcode').data('pcode');

$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");

 console.log("--pcodetable -----");
console.log(pcodetable);
if(pcodetable==pcode){

console.log("match one vale");
$(this).find('td .qty').val(qty);

}
});

 });
```

What is the problem is it because of modal or data table paging? Please help me, how can I update

**I solved my problem:**
later I use **$(document).on('change', '.qtypr', function(){**
instead of **$('.qtypr').on('change',function(){**
because previous line was not able to find qtypr class in the dom and using $(document).on it help me to find the area or class qtypr